# Branches missed in testing JUnit and EclEmma

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, code-coverage

I'm using EclEmma to test the coverage of the test class I have written (JUnit testing). I have enabled the assertions in Java using `-ea`. After running the coverage test, where I have used Java assertions(in the actual code, not the test code of course), it says that that `x` branches of `y` missed. How can I cover all the branches? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: and without assertions it's working fine?

Comment: If I turn off Java assertion, so when I remove -ea argument, I get much lower coverage. My test class covers everything except Java assertions which are shown in yellow and the message I stated in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking why you get lower coverage when you disable your assertions?
This happens because the compiler inserts new branches for asserts. Consider this example:

```
assert x > 0;
```

The compiler will insert code that corresponds roughly to

```
if (assertions are enabled) {
    if ( ! x > 0 )
        throw new AssertionViolatedException()
    }
}
```

This adds branches to your code, and none of those are executed when you turn of assertions. That will drop your coverage ratio, but that's not big deal, as this refers to compiler generated code.

Comment: the question was about when the assertions are enabled.

Comment: My question was, why my test code misses branches. And that happens if assertions ARE ENABLED.

Comment: OK, please rephrase your question so that I can understand it. You run your tests with the '-ea- flag. What happens? Then you run your tests without the '-ea' flag. What happens?